# How to access Win 2008 RC2 on Azure over WinRS in non-domain situation?

Tags: windows, remote-access, azure

I enabled WinRM on both client and server:

```
winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
```

States:

```
Listener
Address = *
Transport = HTTP
Port = 5985
Hostname
Enabled = true
URLPrefix = wsman
CertificateThumbprint
```

On client `TrustedHosts` in `winrm/config/client` equals to `<local>,MYWINRMSERVERNAME`

On server `TrustedHosts` in `winrm/config/client` equals to `<local>,MYWINRMCLIENTNAME`

Windows Firewall: `Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)` rule — enabled on client and server.

For

```
winrs -r:MYWINRMSERVERNAME -u:MYWINRMSERVERNAME\USERNAME -p:PASS cmd.exe
```

It wrote:

> Winrs error:WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the
>   specified computer xception for the WinRM service is enabled and
>   allows access from this computer. By ters within the same local
>   subnet.

Comment: I found the answer. It turned out that I need to allow 5985 port under Azure management. And it works. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. It turned out that I need to allow 5985 port under Azure management. And it works. Hope it will help someone.